# How connect Yii with WYSIWYG editor with uploading images?

Tags: php, image, frameworks, yii, wysiwyg

Any extension? Or example code, help please)

Comment: Have you tried http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/newtinymce/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with redactorjs.
Here is the extension page:
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-redactorjs-wysiwyg-widget

And you should also look to the docs:
http://redactorjs.com/docs/

I hope this will help.